# How to find source of System.ExecutionEngineException Exception

Tags: c#, exception, executionengineexception

I have a very large application. 
And my application throw System.ExecutionEngineException sometimes and I cant find source of this Exception.
Is there any way find it?

Answer (score 0):

Use WinDBG. For this kind of errors it will give you much more information.

[Download and Install Debugging Tools for Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009)

You can download previous versions so you don0t need to download the full DDK.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to catch error on live system, you can add logger to your application and write method name/line/other information about where the error occurs into the log(this will certainly work in debug mode). Its not that hard to add such thing even into large project. See http://nlog-project.org/ or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664569(v=PandP.50).aspx or smth else. If the system is not live-you can catch error with debug. Do it step-by-step(use F10, F11 in Visual Studio) and you will find it for sure!